# how to run only training step in a sagemaker pipeline?

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

based on the docs, we can create different steps and chain them together in sagemaker pipeline, but I am wondering, if i wanted to just run one training step, without processing step , like in the example below, will i able to pass a s3 location as an argument , instead of the output from previous step , i.e. step_process. or in other words , how can i pass a s3 location uri instead of =>
step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs["train"].S3Output.S3Uri

```
    inputs={
        "train": TrainingInput(
            s3_data=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs[
                "train"
            ].S3Output.S3Uri,
            content_type="text/csv"
        ),
        "validation": TrainingInput(
            s3_data=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs[
                "validation"
            ].S3Output.S3Uri,
            content_type="text/csv"
        )
    }
```

```
from sagemaker.workflow.pipeline_context import PipelineSession

from sagemaker.inputs import TrainingInput
from sagemaker.workflow.steps import TrainingStep

from sagemaker.xgboost.estimator import XGBoost

pipeline_session = PipelineSession()

xgb_estimator = XGBoost(..., sagemaker_session=pipeline_session)

step_args = xgb_estimator.fit(
    inputs={
        "train": TrainingInput(
            s3_data=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs[
                "train"
            ].S3Output.S3Uri,
            content_type="text/csv"
        ),
        "validation": TrainingInput(
            s3_data=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs[
                "validation"
            ].S3Output.S3Uri,
            content_type="text/csv"
        )
    }
)

step_train = TrainingStep(
    name="TrainAbaloneModel",
    step_args=step_args,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

*The pipeline, in the context of Amazon SageMaker, refers to a set of interconnected (and not) steps.* See '[SageMaker Pipelines Overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/pipelines-sdk.html)'

*If you define a pipeline that way, you cannot change its runtime configuration. For example, if you define that a training step requires preprocessing data, you cannot change this option.*

---

**The only possible solution** is to create a different pipeline definition script (cleaner and safer solution, to avoid regressions or various errors) or clearly replace the code where you indicate step elements you do not want to use.

---

P.S.: Clearly you will have to:

1. Remove the step from the list of steps to be executed in the pipeline definition:

   `steps=[step_process, step_train]` become `steps=[step_train]`
2. Remove any dependencies between steps.

   E.g. `step_train.add_depends_on([step_process])`